# Spring boot application not mapping the urls

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm learning springboot, when I created a springboot projet and opening `http:localhost:8080/` or

`http:localhost:8080/home`

I faced the below error even though I don't have configured any static files, it is directly showing as No static resource.

Project structure:

[image]

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource .
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource .
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
```

Job Controller:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Component
public class JobController {

    @RequestMapping({"/","home"})
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.16</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--
        https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl/jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars.bower/jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Stack Trace:

```
C:\Users\Lenovo\.jdks\openjdk-21.0.2\bin\java.exe "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=58276:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\JobApp\target\classes;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.2.3\spring-boot-starter-web-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.2.3\spring-boot-starter-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.2.3\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.14\logback-classic-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.14\logback-core-1.4.14.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.21.1\log4j-to-slf4j-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.21.1\log4j-api-2.21.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.12\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\2.2\snakeyaml-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.2.3\spring-boot-starter-json-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.4\jackson-databind-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.4\jackson-annotations-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.4\jackson-core-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.4\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.4\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.2.3\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.19\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.19.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.19\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.19.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.19\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.19.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.1.4\spring-web-6.1.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.1.4\spring-beans-6.1.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.12.3\micrometer-observation-1.12.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.12.3\micrometer-commons-1.12.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.1.4\spring-webmvc-6.1.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.1.4\spring-aop-6.1.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.1.4\spring-context-6.1.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.1.4\spring-expression-6.1.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper\10.1.16\tomcat-jasper-10.1.16.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-servlet-api\10.1.16\tomcat-servlet-api-10.1.16.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-juli\10.1.16\tomcat-juli-10.1.16.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jsp-api\10.1.19\tomcat-jsp-api-10.1.19.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-el-api\10.1.16\tomcat-el-api-10.1.16.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\jdt\ecj\3.33.0\ecj-3.33.0.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-jasper-el\10.1.16\tomcat-jasper-el-10.1.16.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-api\10.1.16\tomcat-api-10.1.16.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-util-scan\10.1.16\tomcat-util-scan-10.1.16.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\tomcat-util\10.1.16\tomcat-util-10.1.16.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-devtools\3.2.3\spring-boot-devtools-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.2.3\spring-boot-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.2.3\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.2.3.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\projectlombok\lombok\1.18.30\lombok-1.18.30.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\jakarta\servlet\jsp\jstl\jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api\3.0.0\jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-3.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\jakarta\servlet\jakarta.servlet-api\6.0.0\jakarta.servlet-api-6.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\jakarta\el\jakarta.el-api\5.0.0\jakarta.el-api-5.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\web\jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl\3.0.1\jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-3.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.12\slf4j-api-2.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.1.4\spring-core-6.1.4.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.1.4\spring-jcl-6.1.4.jar com.projects.JobApp.JobAppApplication



2024-03-14T14:21:27.434+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] com.projects.JobApp.JobAppApplication    : Starting JobAppApplication using Java 21.0.2 with PID 8 (D:\JobApp\target\classes started by Lenovo in D:\JobApp)
2024-03-14T14:21:27.438+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] com.projects.JobApp.JobAppApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-14T14:21:27.573+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-03-14T14:21:27.573+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-03-14T14:21:29.239+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-03-14T14:21:29.253+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-03-14T14:21:29.253+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-03-14T14:21:29.561+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
2024-03-14T14:21:29.572+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-03-14T14:21:29.574+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1999 ms
2024-03-14T14:21:30.027+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-03-14T14:21:30.151+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-03-14T14:21:30.168+05:30  INFO 8 --- [  restartedMain] com.projects.JobApp.JobAppApplication    : Started JobAppApplication in 3.484 seconds (process running for 4.301)
2024-03-14T14:21:48.915+05:30  INFO 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-14T14:21:48.915+05:30  INFO 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-14T14:21:48.915+05:30  INFO 8 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
```

I don't how  it is working and it is directly mapping to Static resources.
Can any one help me on this to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. JobController class is annotated with @component, replace it with @Controller.
2. Replace RequestMapping({"/","home"}) with @RequestMapping("/home"),